# Cannot open an external hard drive in Windows

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive, ntfs, wubi

In Windows 7, I was installing Ubuntu using [Wubi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) (Windows-based Ubuntu installer) to an external hard drive when suddenly it disconnected from the PC. After I connected it back to the PC, and double clicked the drive's icon, Windows didn't show the content of the disk but asked me whether I wanted to format it. The hard drive has only one partition. Its format is NTFS.

I also connected the disk to Windows XP. It makes the Windows Explorer super slow and I cannot open the disk either.

I can open the disk on Ubuntu and Mac.

Is it possible to restore the disk and make it run in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the drive has been formatted to NTFS?  Without knowing exactly what happened in your installation utility (I've not used it in a while, but I don't think Wubi should format to a non-Microsoft format, but I can't assume that either), it may have formatted as something else.  I would try booting into a Linux LiveCD to check.  Otherwise, it may have been corrupted.  Perhaps your USB connections were not stable and data was half-written to the drive.

If you're worried about getting data off of it, there are utilities you can find online for recovering files off of a formatted hard drive.  I've had success with some.  However, it has been a year since I've had to do this so I cannot find the name of the software I used off-hand.  But a Google search will probably turn up a lot of useful solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into a Live CD ([Linux](http://www.livecdlist.com/ubuntu) or [UBCD4Win](http://www.ubcd4win.com/)) and formating it from there.